# How to get real ip address from user client when visit my website using rails in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geokit

i want to get real ip address from user client when visit my website using rails in development mode?

but when i typing `request.remote_ip`, i get ip address `127.0.0.1`??

how to get real ip address???

and when i try `curl -H"X-Forwarded-For: 8.8.8.8" http://httpbin.org/ip`, i get my real ip address but when i try implements gem https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails to get country based ip address... my ip it's not valid?

i try this :

```
IpGeocoder.geocode('my.real.ip.address')
```

and get error like this :

```
Geokit::Geocoders::GeocodeError: Geokit::Geocoders::GeocodeError
```

but if i try ip adrress from example :

```
IpGeocoder.geocode('12.215.42.19')
```

it's works

```
=> Provider: hostip
Street: 
City: Aurora
State: TX
Zip: 
Latitude: 33.0582
Longitude: -97.5159
Country: US
Success: true
```

whats wrong in my ip address? i get my real ip address from "curl -H"X-Forwarded-For: 8.8.8.8" http://httpbin.org/ip"

if i wrong plase tell me, thanks

Comment: Are you using a proxy on your client or server side?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea which may help:

---

**Localhost**

When you load the Rails server in development, you're accessing *your* localhost. This means that any requests made to this server are going to be treated as *local* connections (`127.0.0.1`)

You have to remember Rails is a *server-side* technology, which means it can only process requests as received (it has no bearing on where those requests come from). You can see a glimpse of this with the [ActiveDispatch::Request](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-local-3F) middleware:

> local?()
>   True if the request came from localhost, 127.0.0.1.

This means if you send a request to your local Rails server, it'll just treat it as a local request (`127.0.0.1`)

---

**GeoLocation IP**

Your Geolocation worked for your [WAN IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_area_network) (your remote IP) manually

The reason is because the GeoLocation API / service which the gem uses will ping a third-party server, which will either look up the DNS or other geographic locations for that IP:

From [GeoKit GitHub](https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails):

> IP-based location lookup utilizing hostip.info. Provide an IP address,
>   and get city name and latitude/longitude in return

Like any API, the response will depend on the input. The problem is that because Rails is treating your requests as *local* (from `12.7.0.0.1`), it will only send that IP, which has no bearing on GeoLocation (it's local to your system, not the world)

---

**JS**

To get around this, you'll have to find a way to find your system's WAN IP in development, which you may be able to do with JS:

[How to get client's IP address using javascript only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript) (see Chad Grant's answer):

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    function getip(json){
      alert(json.ip); // alerts the ip address
    }
</script>

<script type="application/javascript" src="http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=getip"></script>
```

I've not tested this, but hopefully it will give you an ideas as to what might be going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to create a tunnel to your local server.